# Central style sheet for react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am learning how develop react native development and I am curious if you could put all the styles into one style.js file and then export it which allow all the components to be able to use the styles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can. u can write styles in seperate file.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ...
});

module.exports = styles;
```

Then import it in componnet class like

```
import styles from './styles'
```

Comment: Thanks for answering!